# How to disable "clipboard" message in Ionic Barcode Scanner

Tags: ionic-framework, clipboard, barcode, ngcordova

I've successfully implemented ngCordova's Barcode Scanner and it works fine. However, everytime it scans, a message popup saying "has been copied to the clipboard". I want to get rid of that message... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the solution is set parameter resultDisplayDuration: 0.

Ex.:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  },
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  },
  {
      preferFrontCamera : true, // iOS and Android
      showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
      showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
      torchOn: true, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
      prompt : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
      resultDisplayDuration: 0, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500
      formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
      orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
      disableAnimations : true, // iOS
      disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS
  }
```

);

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.